# How to load a page using jquery load in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, url

I am trying to load a page using jquery load function in laravel. My code is,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        id = this.id;
        $('#div-details').load('{{URL::to("users/details/'+id+'/view")}}');
    });
});
```

When I try this code I am getting an error,

```
syntax error, unexpected ''+id+'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
```

When I try the load function without `id` variable works fine. Like,

```
 $('#div-details').load('{{URL::to("users/details/55/view")}}');
```

How can I load the `id` properly ?

Comment: Can you try `id = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: Pls provide us with button html markup too.

Comment: Hit static url _not the expression you wrote_ like `$('#div-details').load('users/details/55/view');`. can you post the result of it.

Comment: @jai It correctly loaded the view when using static url

Comment: @VinodVT then you can use it: `$('#div-details').load('users/details/'+id+'/view');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work perfectly when I use like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#div-details').load('{{URL::to("users/details/")}}/'+id+'/view');  // Load like this
});});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass it as a legal path, check the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#div-details').load('users/details/'+id+'/view');
});});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing worlds.

Take a look, you defined the `id` variable in JavaScript:

```
id = this.id;
```

But then later you use it in PHP

```
{{URL::to("users/details/'+id+'/view")}}
```

You cannot use a JavaScript variable in PHP. JavaScript runs in the browser and PHP runs on the server. What you have to do is use PHP to generate the javaScript code that initialises the variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        id = '{{$i}}';
        $('#div-details').load('{{URL::to("users/details/'+id+'/view")}}');
    });
});
```

That sample code assumes the `$id` variable is passed to the view via your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it simply :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
      var id = this.id;
      var url = "users/details/"+id+"/view";
      $('#div-details').load(url);
  });
});
// Another Way 
$(document).on('click','.btn', function(){
      var id = this.id;
      var url = "users/details/"+id+"/view";
      $('#div-details').load(url);
  });
});
```

Keep coding, and keep sharing your resource.